# HAProxy + Keycloak redirect issue

Tags: load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy, keycloak

I have an HAProxy acting as a load balancer in front of 2 machines running  Keycloak in standalone mode.

**Versions**

- HAProxy version 1.6.3, released 2015/12/25
- Keycloak version
  2.4.0.Final

**HAProxy config**

```
global
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  log /dev/log local0
  log-tag WARDEN
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  daemon
  quiet
  stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats level admin
  maxconn 256
  pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
  tune.bufsize 262144

defaults
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client 5000ms
  timeout server 5000ms
  log global
  mode http
  option httplog
  option dontlognull
  option redispatch
  retries 5
  stats uri /haproxy-status

frontend http-in
  mode http
  bind *:80
  maxconn 2000
  redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

frontend https
  mode http
  default_backend servers
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/authhomolog2.portaltecsinapse.com.br/combined.pem
  maxconn 2000
  option forwardfor
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-For %[src]
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https

backend servers
  mode http
  balance source
  cookie JSESSIONID prefix
  server master 172.30.0.74:8080 maxconn 32 check cookie master
  server slave 172.30.0.124:8080 maxconn 32 check cookie slave
```

**Keycloak relevant configs**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default"
                  socket-binding="http"
                  proxy-address-forwarding="true"
                  redirect-socket="proxy-https"/>
...
...

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="proxy-https" port="443"/>
...
...
```

When I try to login in a Java application that uses Keycloak as Single Sign-On, I got the 403 Forbidden error on the screen:

**HAProxy log**

> Dec 16 13:18:49 keycloak-haproxy-test WARDEN[8714]:
> 191.205.78.16:35794 [16/Dec/2017:13:18:48.582] https~ servers/**master** 487/0/0/72/559 **302** 2765 - - --NN 2/2/0/1/0 0/0 "GET
> /realms/BMW/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=BMWGestaoDealer&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fhomolog2gd.bmwbic.com.br%2Ffavicon.ico&state=81%2F4ad46389-fe45-4dec-b804-5563c29c51db&login=true&scope=openid
>
> HTTP/1.1" Dec 16 13:18:49 keycloak-haproxy-test WARDEN[8714]:
> 54.233.89.231:54608 [16/Dec/2017:13:18:48.606] https~ servers/**slave** 552/0/0/4/556 **400** 457 - - --NN 2/2/0/1/0 0/0 "POST
> /realms/BMW/protocol/openid-connect/token HTTP/1.1"

I realized that the request that the GET request started on my machine (191.205.78.16) was responded by **master** Keycloak machine and the redirected POST request started by the application server (54.233.89.231) was responded by the **slave** Keycloak machine. I want all these request to get responded by the same machine (master or slave). Do you know how I do that? I've tried a lot of different configuration in HAProxy without success. :-(

Just one more information, if I leave just the master or the slave Keycloak instance up it works fine.

**Keycloak slave log**

> 2017-12-16 14:43:13.235 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1)
> type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=BMW, clientId=BMWGestaoDealer,
> userId=null, ipAddress=54.233.89.231, error=invalid_code,
> grant_type=authorization_code,
> code_id=52204563-53c8-4c72-bd8c-cb7540ebda3b,
> client_auth_method=client-secret

I'd appreciate any help here.

Comment: Exact same situation here, any update on this? :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with Haproxy or keycloak, but it looks like a problem with session stickiness. So my guess is, sticky sessions should be enable on the haproxy side so that he could remain on the same backend as redirection occurs. Hope it gives you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Could try adding `nocache` in the haproxy configuration file.

Excatly here: `cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache`

I hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here in case it is useful: try using

```
option httpclose
```

or

```
option http-server-close
```

to the backend configuration. Looking at https://www.haproxy.org/download/2.0/doc/configuration.txt, use of the prefix option to append the selected server requires HTTP close mode (i.e. HAPROXY has to use a new backend connection every time).